# gadget's name used as parameter on a method

Tags: c#

```
enter code here:
        //Displays the primary color
        var ralnr = 9004;
        var primColor = 2;
        String primaryColor = column[firstIndex, primColor];
        var primary = ralcode(primaryColor, out ralnr);
        primaryRAL.Text = primaryColor + " " + "RAL" + " " + ralnr;

        PictureBox gadget1 = primaryColorBox1;
        string ral1 = ralnr.ToString();
        backgroundcolorchange(gadget1, ral1);

        //Displays the secondary color
        var secColor = 3;
        String secondaryColor = column[firstIndex, secColor];
        var secondary = ralcode(secondaryColor, out ralnr);
        secondaryRAL.Text = secondaryColor + " " + "RAL" + " " + ralnr; ;

        PictureBox gadget2 = secondaryColorBox2;
        string ral2 = ralnr.ToString();
        backgroundcolorchange(gadget2, ral2);
```

> hi I'm just new in programming. I was trying to pass the gadget's name
>   for    the first gadget and it worked using the Method that I have
>   created but for   the second gadget it did not worked. How is that?

---

```
private void backgroundcolorchange(PictureBox gadget, string ralcode)
{
    string strPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\images\\";
    gadget.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(strPath + ralcode + ".jpg");
    gadget.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
}
```

Comment: Please type your code into the question, not links to screenshots. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that primaryColorBox1 is a textbox?

Based on that guess, you would need to pass the whole object to backgroundcolorchange.
This is because you are trying to alter properties off of the textbox.

so your backgroundcolorchange method would be more like

```
   private void backgroundcolorchange(TextBox gadget, string ralcode){ ...
```

But this is all I can guess based on the information supplied.

Comment: sorry the Picture that I tried uploading here to show the problem didn't upload. The gadget is an image container (*picturebox), whenever I press a button it looks for the string and changes the image background according to the string.